# C segmentation fault core dumped

Tags: c, list, linked-list, segmentation-fault

i'm trying to create a simple linked list program but i'm encountered this problem. I believe the "segmentation fault and core dumped" issue has something to do with memory but could someone please explain how i would fix this problem.

EDIT: ERROR occurs after the first print statement in the main function in list_mgr.c

Here's the course code, i have to source files(list_mgr.c, list_funcs.c) and a header file(list_funcs.h)
Here's list_mgr.c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
     #include "list_funcs.h"
     struct test_struct *head = NULL;
     struct test_struct *curr = NULL;
     int main(void) {
    struct data_node *first, *new_node, *ptr;
    printf("Insert first node into list\n");
    first=ptr=insert(&first, 5);
    strcpy(ptr->name,"Alpha");
    ptr=insert(&first, 7);
    strcpy(ptr->name,"Beta");
    ptr=insert(&first, 3);
    strcpy(ptr->name,"Charlie");
    dump_list(first);

    printf("Search found: ");
    ptr=find_node(first, 5);
    dump_node(ptr);
    printf("Deleting non-1st node.\n");
    delete(&first, 7);
    dump_list(first);



    return 0;

    }
```

here's list_funcs.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list_funcs.h"
struct data_node * insert (struct data_node **p_first, int elem) {


    struct data_node *new_node, *prev, *current;
    current=*p_first;
    while (current != NULL && elem > current->data) {
        prev=current;
        current=current->next;
    } /* end while */
/* current now points to position *before* which we need to insert */
    new_node = (struct data_node *) malloc(sizeof(struct data_node));
    new_node->data=elem;

    new_node->next=current;
    if ( current == *p_first ) /* insert before 1st element */
        *p_first=new_node; 
    else                       /* now insert before current */
        prev->next=new_node;
/* end if current == *p_first */
    return new_node;
};

struct data_node * find_node (struct data_node *p, int elem) {
while (p != NULL) {
   if ( elem == p->data )
      return p;
   p=p->next;
   } /* end while */
}; /* end find_node */

void dump_node (struct data_node *current) {
printf("Dumping node: ");
if (current != NULL)
   printf("%s: %d\n", current->name, current->data);
}; /* end dump_list */


void dump_list (struct data_node *current) {
    printf("List dump:\n");
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%s: %d\n", current->name, current->data);
        current=current->next;
    } /* end while */
    printf("\n");
}; /* end dump_list */

int delete (struct data_node **p_first, int elem) {
    int retval = 0;
    struct data_node *current, *prev;
    current=*p_first;
    while (current != NULL && elem != current->data ) {
        prev=current;
        current=current->next;
   }
    if (current == NULL) /* element not found */
        return retval;
/* current now points to node to delete */
    if ( current == *p_first ) /* delete 1st node */
        *p_first = (*p_first)->next;
    else  /* link previous to next thus skipping over node to delete */
        prev->next=current->next;
        free(current);
        retval=1;
    return retval;
}; /* end delete */
```

and here's the headerfile

```
 #define STRINGMAX 25

struct data_node {
   char name [STRINGMAX];
   int data;
   struct data_node *next;
   };



struct data_node * insert (struct data_node **, int);
struct data_node * find_node (struct data_node *, int);
void dump_list (struct data_node *); 
int delete (struct data_node **, int);
void dump_node (struct data_node *);
```

Comment: So much code and not even a mention of the line which causes the error.

Comment: edited to answer that question, ERROR occurs after the first print statement in the main function in list_mgr.c

Comment: Seg-Fault has to do with memory! It is an error from the OS that some process is trying to do something to a memory block that doesn't have the privilege to read or write... This error also kills the process because an illegal action like this (trying to change some memory block out of your bounds) is sneaky (if not a random programming error) and shows that the process that tried this isn't up to anything good (in fact it could destroy some other's process runtime) and has to DIE. So the OS kills the process (your program)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You access an uninitialized variable:

```
int main(void) {
    struct data_node *first, *new_node, *ptr;
    first=ptr=insert(&first, 5);
//...
struct data_node * insert (struct data_node **p_first, int elem) {
    struct data_node *new_node, *prev, *current;
    current=*p_first;
```

`*p_first` is `first` from `main` which was never initialized. So `current` gets a wild value, which you then dereference.

**Edit:** I haven't waded through all your code to try and understand it, but maybe this fix would work:

```
int main(void) {
    struct data_node *first = NULL, *new_node, *ptr;
    ptr=insert(&first, 5);
    first = ptr;
```

I separate the two assignments because sometimes it is undefined to have `a = foo(&a)`.